# Is there a way to access geo-location data in Facebook's Spark AR?

Tags: geolocation, augmented-reality, spark-ar-studio

We want to make some geolocation-based Instagram filters and can't figure out if there's a Geo API or not.

Can I access, maybe at least partially, the geolocation data? I'm interested in both position and compass data.